# Синхронизация времени таймера на разных клиентах

Tags: php, javascript

Как реализовать синхронизацию времени таймера на разных клиентах? Инет облазил четкого ответа нигде не нашел. Хотя бы подскажите в какую сторону копать. Желательно как можно подробнее. Очень буду благодарен.

На данный момент отсчет начинается с момента, когда первый клиент зайдет на сайт. Начинают отправляться асинхронные запросы, получение данных с бд о времени, обновление данных в бд. Но проблема в том, что это всё зависит от клиента (когда же он зайдет). Мне же необходимо чтобы таймером оперировал сам сервер, а не сверял данные поступающие от ajax-запросов. В таком случае таймер будет работать, обновляться и сам розыгрыш будет проходить самостоятельно и не зависеть от клиента.

Comment: Что за таймер, насколько точная синхронизация?

Comment: Под клиентом вы, что имеете в виду?

Comment: @vp_arth Синхронизация в секундах. Таймер на подобии аукциона. Чтобы каждый клиент видел одно и то же время и когда таймер заканчивается у всех одновременно происходил розыгрыш.

Comment: @Mikhail Под клиентом я имею ввиду каждый открытый браузер с этим сайтом

Comment: На сервере источник времени, клиент сверяется с ним через websocket соединение. Или даже обычный heartbeat. Но событие окончания надёжнее получить через websocket.

Comment: Добавьте функцию которая обращается к серверу каждые Н секунд и запрашивает время, оставшееся на аукцион через AJAX запрос.

Comment: с сервера при открытии страницы передаете оставшееся время. на клиенте вычитаете из него `performance.now()` правда будет расхождение на время передачи данных по сети. если этой точности не достаточно, то вам надо будет реализовать на web что то на подобии протокола ntp

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо, гляну!

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Подскажите золотую середину) Какое кол-во секунд лучше, чтобы почаще обновлять и при этом не убить таймер? От него уже буду отталкиваться.

Comment: Таймер точно не убьётся, а по времени ваша середина это то что вы сами поставите - начните с 10 секунд, попробуйте на 5 - и прийдете к комфортабельному выбору.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Спасибо!

Comment: @VladPanchenko Просто передавайте в странице дату-время UTC будущего события, вычисленное на сервере. А клиенты js-ом будут считать, сколько до него осталось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Если же необходимо чтобы таймером оперировал сам сервер.`

Если есть цель создать процес независимо от клиентов, то можно все реализовать на `linux` сервере используя `cron`. Каждые 10 сек к примеру запускать `php` файл и запускать какой то алгоритм для розыгрыша. По поводу времени, вам подойдет функция `time();` на `php` она возвращает время в секундах (int), и его очень удобно использовать для проверки чего либо связаного с времинем. Также `time()` можно конвертировать в `data()`, чтобы красиво смотрелось в браузере. К примеру если 5 клиентов подключены к "комнате" и вдруг отключились, то комната и далее будет существовать и реагировать на время так как ее будет запускать `cron` каждые несколько секунд. Для розыгрыша или покера такой стак технологий подойдет вполне. Это, я считаю, в кое чем класическое решение, если использовать `php`, `ajax`, и линукс сервер. Единственное нужна будет виртуалка с линуксом, рекомендую [digital ocean](https://m.do.co/c/2436beab6df6) (сам использую). Или же хостинг где будет возможность настроить `cron`.